# Computing the joint distribution of correlated random variables

Tags: probability-distributions

This is probably a stupid question but I will have to ask it.

If you had a set of N correlated random variables and knew the correlation matrix, can one compute the joint probability distribution of all variables?

Does it make a difference if the correlation matrix was built using Pearson's rho or Kendall's Tau for example?

Thanks,
Bogdan.

Comment: Knowing the correlation matrix is not enough to determine the joint distribution. This is like saying that the mean of a single random variable is enough to determine its distribution.

Comment: @StefanHansen: In your statement, you might want to change 'mean' to 'variance'.

Comment: @Avatar: Or 'mean and variance'.

Comment: I had this impression too. But do you know of any method at least to estimate the joint? What would be the minimum amount of information required to approximate the joint out of the marginals?

Comment: Like @Stefan said, there is no way to estimate the joint distribution from the correlation matrix. Even the exact marginals + the exact correlation matrix are not enough to estimate the joint distribution.

Comment: I wanted to ask besides the correlation matrix what would be required to estimate the joint?

Comment: If you _know_ or are given that the random variables are _jointly normal_, then knowledge of the mean vector and covariance matrix gives the joint distribution explicitly. Otherwise, as others have already told you, there is nothing that can be said. I recommend [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30205/6633) on stats.SE (to a different question) for some very interesting insights.